# How to load custom dataset from CSV in Huggingfaces

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I would like to load a custom dataset from csv using `huggingfaces-transformers`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading_datasets.html#loading-from-local-files

```py
dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files={'train': "train_set.csv",'test': "test_set.csv"})
```

Comment: how do I name it different ? 'csv' seems to be default argument.

Comment: if you mean that you want to use a different format , such as json, you can substitute 'csv' with 'json'

Comment: Ohh I mean. dataset is saved by name csv. How do I name it like "text_dataset" or something else. More like how I do name the dataset ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `load_dataset` directly as shown in the official [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading#specify-features).

I can't find any documentation about supported arguments, but in my experiments they seem to match those of [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```py
file_dict = {
  "train" : "train.csv",
  "test" : "test.csv"
}

load_dataset(
  'csv',
  data_files=file_dict,
  delimiter=',',
  column_names=['column01', 'column02', 'column03'],
  skiprows=1
)
```